What is the smallest finite group $G$ with a proper nontrivial noncentral subgroup $H$ to have a non-abelian centralizer $C_G(H) \neq G$?
What is the smallest finite group G with a proper nontrivial noncentral subgroup H to have a non-abelian centralizer C(H)≠G in G?
I found one: the alternating group A6 of order 360, non-abelian simple, ie. with trivial center.
Its 45 subgroups of isom. type C2 have centralizers Dih4 = $D_8$ of order 8 in A6, ie. non-abelian.
Are there any smaller ones ??

@verret: thank you for yr comments! Of course, any central element and hence the center and all its subgroups have the full G as centralizer trivially. I am looking for centralizers $C_G(H)$≠G in G, and should have made this explicit!

Done. I took out the CA part since it is too trivial to obtain non-CA groups, and thus eg. the Pauli group is trivially non-CA and thus nonabelian, too.

PS ... and I honestly did not know that it is nec. or at least good practice in MSE to repeat the Q in the OP again - seems I learnt sth important, and flog myself to not knowing this before. thx

The smallest example is $G=S_4$, of order $24$, with $H$ a cyclic group of order $2$ generated by a double transposition, and the centraliser of $H$ is dihedral of order $8$.

Merci! - that is a great example. It so happens that $S_5$ also has the desired property, and there even ALL subgroups of type $C_2$ have dihedral groups as centralizers.

Your answer is the correct one of course, but I still feel that $G=S_3\times S_3$ is an "easier" example (and then one sees that any $H\times K$ with $H$, $K$ non-abelian will do, and ought to have been excluded from the spec.)

@ancient mathematician: how very true - that is a fine one! Out of 14 subgroups of $G$ of type $S_3$ two are normal, and eg. isom. to $1\times S_3$ with centralizer $S_3 \times 1$ and v.v. Thence their $C2$ non-normal subgroups in turn also have a non-abelian centralizer, the dihedral group of order 12. Excluding these kind of $G$ still leaves us with the earlier semidirect examples. But this one is educational, too. merci

Dessert: Realizing that all of the examples so far are centerless groups ($Z(G) \cong C_1$), are there any non-centerless groups G with a proper nontrivial noncentral subgroup H to have a non-abelian centralizer C(H)≠G in G??

@HaraldB Take a direct product with an abelian group?

Indeed, e.g. $C_2 x S_4$ is such a non-trivial example. Six of its non-normal $C_2$ are centralised by $C_2 x D_8$ of order 16, and their centraliser in turn is $V_4 > C_2$, as required.
